# Extend Display to 4 monitors from desktop and 4 monitors from Laptop with some other details. Can it be Done?

Tags: multiple-monitors, switch, splitter, extended-desktop

I have a HP Envy desktop 750-514 PC (attaching pictures of the back, 4 USB SS, and 2 HDMI ports)

I will have a work lap top ( 2 USB SS, 1 HDMI, 1 VGA)

I own 2 HP 23 ES monitors (1 HDMI, 1 VGA in)

I also have 5 ACER V233HL Monitors (1 DVI in, 1 VGA in)

I would like to be able to run 4 of the acer monitors off of the lap top (can not provide model info until 1/4/2020)

I would also like to run the 2 HP monitors, as well as 2 Acer monitors off of the desk top, and if possible also run an output line to my Sharp ROKU TV.

I want each set of monitors to run as extended displays

I have a 6 monitor stand.  I envision the 2 monitors on the right hand side to be the HP, and then the 2 in the middle as well as the 2 on the left to be the Acers. The 2 in the middle would be the ones on a switch so I could toggle them back and forth from the work Lap Top to my home desk top.

My work lap top is used exclusively for using a cloud software program, internet research, and the microsoft office suite

My desktop computer will likewise mostly be used for school work purposes, so mostly running microsoft, as well as online classes, internet research and that sort of thing.  However, I do intend on taking some coding classes and would like to be set up for using Python and some other Data Analysis programs, and may possibly want to use it for Audio recording/editing and video editing.

Can this be done?

What equipment/hubs would I need?  Can this just be done with hubs, or am I going to have to get a graphics card for the desktop?  I won't be able to modify the work laptop in anyway physically, so can I run 4 monitors with a hub from the HDMI and a Hub from the USB SS?

Would truly appreciate any help and advice anyone can offer, as I have never tried anything like this before, and just came into this new monitor stand and all of these extra monitors.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a broad question, so here's a bit of a broad answer;)

You'd need at minimum a second GPU for the desktop & an eGPU for the laptop… if it will even take one. There are very few laptops that can run 4 external displays & none that I know of that don't do it with Thunderbolt.

Most will support a 4k screen these days, same as your 4 Acers. In fact, economically, it would probably be cheaper to just get 2 decent modern screens & a KVM switch.

Comment: So, If I understand you correctly, there would be no way to run the 4 screens off of the lap top just using 2 splitters, one that went from the HDMI and one that went from either the USB or The VGA (or maybe one from each of the USB ports)?

Any recommendations on GPU's to install?  Will the HP Envy even be able to support a GPU of that Caliber?

For the Laptop, am I to understand that pretty much any laptop at best is only going to support 2 external screens?

Comment: I'm not against getting rid of the Acer Monitors and trading them in for a "newer" monitor that is more compatible, but I would really like to be able to add at least a 3rd external screen for the lap top as I really hate flipping back and forth between windows when working on projects etc.  What KVM switch would I need (and maybe the monitors to go with it as well?)  I had been running to Hanns G 19 inch screens off of the laptop, one from the HDMI and one from the VGA

Comment: Wow! Too many questions. You can't "split" video signals unless you want the same image on each. They must each be fed as an independent entity. USB cannot carry video. VGA is so old it's not built into any computer these days, so you'd need a converter. Hardware recommendations are off-topic. HP Envy is a brand name covering many computers over many years.

Comment: HOw is a hardware recommendation off topic?  I want the HP to be able to handle 4 or more screens, but it isn't for video game play.  I see that the tower has enough space to add a graphics card, I want to know if my system can handle a more advance graphics card and which one I should buy.

The specs are:

7th generation INtel Core  i5-7400 processor
1.2 GB ddr4-2133 SDRAM memory
1TB Hard Drive
1.2 GB SATA Solid State drive
Intel HD Graphics 630

Comment: How is it off-topic? Because the community decided long ago that it is off-topic. See https://superuser.com/help/on-topic It's off-topic right across Stack Exchange, except for https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what laptop you got, but I run an [eGPU via Thunderbolt](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005004167110499.html) (USB-C) from my ThinkPad T480.

[image: TH3P4 Mini GPU Dock]
The card is a cheap old GTX 950 that happily runs three 4K monitors  @60 Hz via its 3 DisplayPort connectors:

[image: GTX 950 Gaming 2G]

I could connect one more HDMI and one more DVI monitor to that eGPU.